# how to use a class in other class phpunit?

Tags: php, oop, composer-php, phpunit

hello I am trying to organize my classes in the composer-phpunit format, my classes already work interlacing them with require but I would like to have my code by folders and not all the files in the src folder my structure is the following

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Agxm.png)

I thought that adding two namespaces in the psr-4 attribute of the composer file would work this is the structure of my composer file

```
{
    "name": "ramirogg/p4wsnc",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type":"vcs",
            "url":"https://github.com/r4m1r0gg/PIEZAS_4_WEBSITES_NEW_CONCEPT"
        }
    ],
    "description": "p4wsnc library",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "p4wsncbase\\": "src/clases_base/",
            "p4wsnctobase\\": "src/clases_directas_ala_base/"
        },
        "files": [
            "src/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5@dev"
    }
}
```

This is the head class and this is how I defined the namespace

```
<?php

namespace p4wsncbase;

class Head {
 //here is all my code if you need to see it let me know
}
```

this is the sethead class and this is how i call the head class

```
<?php

namespace p4wsnctobase;
use p4wsncbase\Head;

class SetHead {}
```

in the same way I do it for the other classes I have an even class for each class within the classes_base folder, for example for the head class I have the sethead class for the body class I have the setbody class and for the tag class I have the settag class the classes that start with set are in the folder classes_directas_ala_base

finally this is how I call the classes sethead, setbody and settag in the index

```
<?php 
    
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    use p4wsnctobase\SetHead;
    use p4wsnctobase\SetBody;
    use p4wsnctobase\SetTag;
```

I would like to thank you forever, I really would like to maintain this structure, thank you very much in advance

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error message?

Comment: no, the problem is that I do not get anything on screen as if the classes are not recognized, but when using require directly removing the namespaces  everything works ...

Comment: Did you dump your composer autoload?

Comment: What do you mean by "the composer-phpunit format"? What's the exact problem you are facing? "I do not get anything on screen" looks pretty obvious for the given set of classes, as they don't contain any methods, are not used anywhere, and even the rest of the given code does not contain anything that could be printed

Comment: bassxzero yes ,Nico Haase 
i just meant i am working with composer and phpunit, exactly "as they don't contain any methods, are not used anywhere, and even the rest of the given code does not contain anything that could be printed"